# How to build a NixOps deployment on hydra

Tags: nix, nixos

Deploying my NixOps machines takes alot of time, as packages need to build. I want to do the building regularly on my trusted private Hydra instance.

My current approach involves this `release.nix` file, but it doesn't work out so well.

```
{ nixpkgs ? <nixpkgs>, onlySystem ? true, extraModules ? [] }:

let

  nixos = import "${nixpkgs}/nixos";

  buildEnv = conf: (nixos {
    configuration = conf;
  });
  buildTarget = m: let build = buildEnv (buildConf m); in
    if onlySystem then build.system else build.vm;

  buildConf = module: { ... }:
    {
      imports = [ module ] ++ extraModules;
    };

in

{
  machine1 = buildTarget ./machine1/configuration.nix;
  machine2 = buildTarget ./machine2/configuration.nix 
  machine3 = buildTarget ./machine3/configuration.nix 
  machine4 = buildTarget ./machine4/configuration.nix 
}
```

I don't really understand this code, as I copied it from [here](https://github.com/freifunkMUC/infra/blob/master/release.nix).

This builds fine if I run `nix-build release.nix` locally, but on hydra I never get a full build. Sometimes builds don't dequeue (they just don't get build), sometimes they fail with various error messages. As nothing of the hydra problems are reproducible (beside the fact, that I never get a full build), I wonder what the best practice for building a NixOps deployment is.

Please note, that I have `unfree` packages in my deployment. The option `nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;` is set on the hydra server.

This is not a question about my hydra failures, but about what would be a good way to build a NixOps deployment with Hydra CI.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to make this super easy. Your code looks ok, but my method is a slightly different. I only build the `toplevel` attribute and I construct the NixOS configuration differently.

I build NixOS 'installations' from inside Nix using something like:

```
let
  modules = [ ./configuration.nix ];
  nixosSystem = import (pkgs.path + "/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix") {
      inherit (pkgs) system;
      inherit modules;
    };
in
  nixosSystem.config.system.build.toplevel
```

Comment: What exactly is `config.system.build.toplevel`? What does it represent? I looked at the output of the derivation and it's a directory that seems to contain a lot of things for stage-1 booting and stage-2 booting.

Comment: It's what gets written to `/nix/var/nix/profiles/system`, which is also the garbage collection root for the system configuration. If anything is missing from it, it may be garbage collected, so this is a good indication that it will include everything the system configuration needs.

Comment: So it's sole purpose is to anchor the system built artifacts to prevent the GC from garbage collecting them? No program actually accesses the files from `/nix/var/nix/profiles/system`. Because these stuff are usually put into the stage-1 initrd, or the init script. I'm guessing that the `etc` directory is also the same as `/etc`?

Comment: The profiles can also be used for reverting to that generation (`system-$N-link` etcetera). `/etc` and its contents are created by the activation script in `toplevel`.